# Windows Service Communicate WIth UI

Tags: c#, wpf, service

At this momment I have a windows service running in the local system and I have a separate project write with WPF. When a service fired one specific event I use CreateProcessAsUser() to open a specific program. But this method create a new instace instead open my instance is running in the startup.I already try working around but the solution i find use WCF.  In my ideia is having some middleware or Agent to to get a instance of my WPF project and route to the right form to be display.

Comment: I'm sorry, I really don't understand what your question is.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147/what-is-the-correct-way-to-create-a-single-instance-application help?

Comment: My question is how i invoke my desktop program already running from windows service